# Showing Google Map on view.blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, laravel-5

Trying to display google map on Laravel's blade. 
Already gave the key and returning the geocode in json code. But I have some displaying issue as a map.

Firstly, I am seeing map just 2 second. I can tell it's not coordinate what give on controller. It shows australia/sydney.

And then map going unseen with error in the picture below.
I have correct API key. No problem with that. the problem is javascript I guess. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Controller:

```
public function map()
    {
        $response = \GoogleMaps::load('geocoding')
            ->setParam ([
                'address'    =>'tokyo',
                'components' => [
                    'country'=> 'JP',
                ]

            ])
            ->get();

        return view('welcome', compact('response'));

    }
```

And my welcome.blade:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
        {{$response}}
    </div>

    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
    </script>
```

But it returns this error on map. 
[image: Error]

Comment: Have you acquired an API key from google to be able to use google maps? If yes, please show what error the console is showing.

Comment: yes already have it. when I don't use javascript above. I can see the access geocoding json format. No problem with that. @BonishKoirala

Comment: Please edit and add in the question with the error you are getting in your console

Comment: Update the question. can u check it again? @BonishKoirala

Comment: The information you have provided is still insufficient. You can check this link [Error Messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) which provides a list of the errors you might be getting while trying to run google maps. Try to match your error that you have got in the console and you may find a solution yourself.

Comment: You might have to include the javascript before the map div

Comment: nope, no effects.